# How to generate an orthogonal symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrix, symmetric, orthogonal

I want to create an orthogonal symmetric matrix of size 5 and size 6. Is there a way for me to generate this type of matrix? An orthogonal symmetric matrix is when a matrix A is equal to its transpose and also its inverse.

I've tried searching for ways to do this but all I get is how to generate an orthogonal matrix or how to generate a symmetric matrix. Couldn't find a way to generate an orthogonal symmetric matrix.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835837/58610) related post?

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?